# Pandas explode creates row with empty cell

Tags: python, pandas, split, explode

I am new to Pandas. I am trying to split a string into multiple rows.
I splitting it to a list and then trying to explode it.
When I explode a list I get a row with an empty value which I don't want.

```
df = df.assign(
    col_a=df["col_a"].str.split("X:")
).explode("col_a")
```

```
col_a                col_b        ...lots of columns with different things
X: word1 X: word2    a
X: word2 X: word3    b
X: word2             c
```

Becomes:

```
col_a                col_b        ...lots of columns with different things
                     a
X: word1             a
X: word2             a
                     b
X: word2             b
X: word3             b
                     c
X: word2             c
```

I want something like:

```
col_a                col_b        ...lots of columns with different things
word1                a
word2                a
word2                b
word3                b
word2                c
```

How do I get rid of these empty cell? I don't want those rows at all.

Thanks!

Comment: That's because when you split your string, the list looks like `[, word1 , word2]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try remove the starting `X:` before `split`:

```
df.assign(
  col_a = df.col_a.str.replace('^X: ', '').str.split(' X: ')
).explode('col_a')

#   col_a col_b
#0  word1     a
#0  word2     a
#1  word2     b
#1  word3     b
#2  word2     c
```